# Node modules installation globally

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

How can i refer to node modules installed globally ? I mean if i have a `package.json` file and i install all the node modules(as per the `package.json` file) globally (at `C:\Users\MyaccountName\AppData\Roaming\npm`) , then how can i refer to these modules?

When I install them globally, and then run my Angular app from my project folder( using `ng serve` command) it says

> "You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core" and/or "rxjs". This
>   is an error."

Is there any way i can keep my node modules globally and run my project? Are there some node modules that always need to be present in my project folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing the below command before executing your `ng serve`,

`npm link`

This `npm link` command creats a symbolic link between your project and your global node modules directory (`C:\Users\MyaccountName\AppData\Roaming\npm`)

Hope this helps!

Comment: it creates node modules folder in my project folder, but i want the node modules to be  in this folder only "C:\Users\MyaccountName\AppData\Roaming\npm" since it consumes a lot of space

Comment: No, you can go like that, you need to have `angular-cli` tools installed globally and the your project's dependencies defined and installed as dev dependencies separtely.